# Create a clockwise gradient in GIMP

Tags: gimp, gradient

I was wondering if anyone knows a relatively easy way to create a clockwise gradient in GIMP.

If you could imagine a vertical line 1ps wide (The length of the radius), and then rotate it 360 degrees, with the bottom of the line being the transform point, with it loosing opacity gradually until it makes a full rotation ... That's basically what I need Lol ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following.

1. Create a new transparent layer and choose the "Blend Tool" and in the tool options, set the gradient to "FG to transparent".

[image: Setup blend tool]

2. Select the color you want to use for the vertical line and draw a gradient from one side of the canvas to the other.

[image: Draw gradient]

3. Go to "Filters->Distorts->Polar Coordinates" and the default settings should be fine but you can make the gradient map go in the opposite direction by checking "Map backwards".

[image: Polar Coordinates filter settings]
[image: Polar Coordinates filter applied]

4. The radius will be half the size of the image at this point but if you want it smaller you can go to "Layer->Scale Layer" and enter the diameter for the width and height. If you want the diameter of the circle to be larger than the image, I suggest you create a new image which is larger and copy and paste the gradient layer to the image you are working with then right click the floating selection layer and choose "To New Layer".

[image: Result]