# How to create a clockwise gradient in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I would like to know whether it is possible to create a circular gradient or alternative one which follows a given path in Inkscape.

This is the effect I would like to create:

[Circular gradient http://liamlime.com/dump/laptop/2015-09-20/2015-09-20_21-28-51.png](http://liamlime.com/dump/laptop/2015-09-20/2015-09-20_21-28-51.png)

To generate this image I created lots of small wedges and manually set each individual wedge's alpha value.

This question was answered for Adobe Illustrator in [How to apply a gradient effect for a particular circular path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30329/how-to-apply-a-gradient-effect-for-a-particular-circular-path) and for Gimp in [Create a clockwise gradient in GIMP](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/create-a-clockwise-gradient-in-gimp), however I was unable to find an answer for Inkscape.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably there is no answer for Inkscape because a conical gradient is not yet in SVG standard, but you can [tweak](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Advanced_Gradients#Conical_gradient) a little and obtain something, see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465405/svg-angular-gradient).

Comment: I vote for the comment by Paolo Gibellini above as answer. I think the "Probably" can be left out :)

Comment: This actually *is* possible in the current stable release (0.91), using the `Create Tiled Cone` feature. See [this tutorial](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.com/2012/01/conical-gradients-in-inkscape.html). I'm hesitant to post this as an answer, since link-only answers are not acceptable, but I'm not sure if it's OK to reproduce (and cite) that tutorial as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Inkscape devel version, there's a conical gradient available (Mesh gradient tool).

You can find it (precompiled) for Ubuntu in the ppa, and for Windows, there are occasional 32bit builds:
https://inkscape.org/en/download/

(can't add more links, else I'd have linked directly. Scroll down to "Development versions")

[image: Screenshot Mesh gradient / conical test case]

**Edit:** I just got the info that it does *not* currently work with 32bit devel versions for Windows, because it requires a newer version of the cairo library. The Ubuntu ppa version works well, though.