# How to fade out tail of path in InkScape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

How can I fade out this path from the bottom point, along the curvature of the circle, to the end point on the right?

[image]

Or in SVG format:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="437.074" height="437.074" viewBox="0 0 409.75714 409.75714">
    <path d="M271.606 46.922c-20.51-8.675-43.058-13.472-66.727-13.472-94.678 0-171.429 76.751-171.429 171.429 0 94.677 76.751 171.428 171.429 171.428 94.677 0 171.428-76.751 171.428-171.428" fill="none" stroke="#008bff" stroke-width="66.9"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Apparently the latest version [supports conical gradients](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/how-to-create-a-clockwise-gradient-in-inkscape) as part of the *mesh gradient* feature.