# Color Gradient Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, gradient-mesh

I've another *question for you* ✨
**I have a circle** and I would like **to fill** it with a **white gradient**;
These are the best example I could do:
[image: conical Color]

**How can I make this effect on Inkscape?**

I feel lost because no sample seems to satisfy my needs.
*Thanks for your attention* and looking forward to your *wonderful ideas*.

Comment: Are you meaning a *conical gradient* like in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/how-to-create-a-clockwise-gradient-in-inkscape)? See also [here](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Advanced_Gradients) and [here](https://logosbynick.com/inkscape-create-conical-gradients/).

Comment: The one on the left would be a conical gradient, which isn't available in Inkscape. You could fake it with a gradient mesh, but quite a bit of work. [Tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU84RopG4Ng&feature=emb_logo).  I'd be tempted instead to just do it in GIMP, which does have an actual conical gradient.  The example on the right is not really a gradient.

Comment: Illustrator can do this Conical Gradient  with a gradient applied to a (thick) stroke. Set Gradient to "Apply Gradient Along Stroke". Circle would need to be "Cut" so the Gradient has a start and stop point. I am not familiar with Inkscape- does it have a similar ability ?

Comment: @Kyle, a gradient along a stroke isn't available in Inkscape. It's not supported in SVG as far as I know, and Inkscape is an SVG editor. SVG (and Inkscape) does support a gradient within a stroke, but not along it.

Comment: .. and although you can do this on a stroke in AI.. the only other option is to expand the stroke in AI afterwards, which yields a gradient mesh, also not supported in SVG.

Comment: @Scott - Illustrator will also rasterize a gradient mesh if you try to export it as SVG. You could also rasterize a gradient mesh in Inkscape, and put it inside a clipping path, [see example](https://svgshare.com/i/Tr2.svg)

Comment: @Paolo Thank you so much for the last 2 links, I solved with Gimp as Billy suggested;
I'm trying to figure out which program to use for every need I have and I will soon have the experience to know 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output this as an SVG, there are a couple of problems.

Inkscape (and the SVG format) doesn't support conical gradients, or gradients along a stroke. Inkscape does have a gradient mesh which you could use to fake a conical gradient [(see Tutorial here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU84RopG4Ng&feature=emb_logo), but gradient meshes aren't supported in SVGs yet. Maybe it will be possible in some later SVG 2.x version, but it's not possible at the moment, and browsers can't display an SVG with a gradient mesh.

A possible work around

If you create a gradient mesh in Inkscape, you could rasterize it using *Edit > Make a bitmap copy*, then put it in a clipping path.

For example:

[image]

Here's the [SVG example (made in Inkscape)](https://svgshare.com/i/Tr2.svg)

Comment: I hope they make this feature possible in SVG asap

Comment: Your last link send me in an error page:( 
Thanks for the idea, I will try with GIMP even if I don't know it very much...