# How can I make "sweep" gradient that resembles a radar or a lightsaber?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, inkscape, svg

Here is the approximate effect I'm describing.

[image]

It's a linear gradient that has been "circlized".  I have Photoshop, Inkscape, or can just notepad some raw svg.

Even just knowing what term to Google for would be useful.

Comment: The terms to google: Angle Gradient, or Conical Gradient. It's not supported in the SVG format. In Inkscape you'd have to rasterize a gradient mesh instead (gradient meshes are not currently supported in SVG either). See [related question here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144888/color-gradient-inkscape/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by many different ways like masking and etc but I'll use photoshop's **Angle Gradient** effect to achieve this one.

1. Create circle shape via shape tool.
2. Remove fill and border.
3. Apply Gradient Effect on circle layer.
4. Change gradient to single color via removing all extra **color nodes** (down pins in gradient editor)
5. Drag **opacity controls** (upper pins in gradient editor) closer and create one more node with 0% opacity and press OK.
6. Change gradient style to **Angle** and customize as you like. Your effect is ready!

Watch below video tutorial if you feels stuck!

[image: Angle Gradient]

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

This is for Inkscape

1. Begin with a circle
2. Select the gradient mesh tool, in the tool controls bar hit the Conical gradient button, set 8 rows and 8 columns, and click and drag on the circle to apply a mesh.
3. Click and drag to select all stops on the gradient, and change the colour to green
4. Select other stops, and change to white
5. Click and drag the arc controls on the circle so you have just one small segment visible.

[image]

Note that gradient meshes aren't supported in SVGs at present. A workaround for this would be to rasterize the mesh object, and place it inside a clipping mask.